# How to use numeric keys with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, orm

Is there a way to use numeric keys for objects with Mongoose? Such as:

```
{
  timestamp_minute: ISODate(“2013-10-10T23:06:00.000Z”),
  num_samples: 58,
  total_samples: 108000000,
  type: “memory_used”,
  values: {
    0: 999999,
    …
    37: 1000000,
    38: 1500000,
    … 
    59: 1800000
  }
}
```

When I save something like this via Mongoose, the keys in values are stored as strings (ex: "0", "1", ... , "59"). Is there any way to make these store as numeric keys?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript object always non-numeric key. If you use numeric key, it will be converted as non-numeric or string.